# How to solve problem with div inside on CSS

Tags: html, css

sorry for my English..

I have problem width the inside div's.

I to want to come like this image,

[image: i to want to come like this image]

but to come this...

[image: window which to come]

Html and Css,

CSS

```
 #tittel-text {padding: 1%; text-align:left;border-bottom:1px hidden; background-color:  #d7a8a8; }

 #closse-text {  color: #f2f2f2; padding: 0.6%;  cursor: pointer; float: right;}


 .text-pruduct {background-color: red;   margin: 1px; padding: 1.7%;  }

 .float_text{ background-color: yellow; float: right;  display: block; margin-top: 3%;  } 

  .bild-text { background-color: #a6a6a6; float: left; display: block; margin-top: 3%; } 



<div class="container">



                       <!-- code open new window -->
                   <div id="layerPreview-3" > </div>
                   <div id='layerPreviewContent-3'>
                           <!-- Mostramos el texto de cerrar para poder cerrar la ventana -->
                          <div id="tittel-text">Erfogreich zum Warenkorb hinzugefügt<span id="closse-text"  onclick="layer_close_3(event);">Schließen</span></div>

                         <div class="text-pruduct">
                            <div class="float_text">
                             <p>Anzahl der Artikel im Waremkorb:  1 </p>
                             <p>Wert des Warenkorbs: </p>
                            </div>
                             <div  class="bild-text">

                                 <img class="image-window" alt=""  src="https://i.imgur.com/64eoSkA.jpg" /> 

                                  <p>Rucksack aus Hanf Gelbe</p> 
                                  <p>Stückzahl: <b>1</b></p>
                                  <p>Bruttopreis: <b>40 &euro; </b></p>
                             </div> 
                             <div class="ajax-product-block"> 
                                    <a class="button_weiter_einkaufen" href="lalo.php">weiter kaufen</a> 
                                    <a class="button_zum_warenkorbs" href="lalo.php">zum warenkorb</a>
                             </div>
                         </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

I tried to come like the first image, but every time to come with problems..

[Hier](https://jsfiddle.net/ichder/7410jz2g/50/) the code only with the problem

Can please someone help me with my mistake?

Comment: What problems/errors exactly? Could you add the Javascript to the JSFiddle please?

Comment: Not, that problem is with CSS

Comment: are you ok to change the HTML structure?

Comment: I'll to come like the first image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the basic idea how you can achieve this structure , now just give the colors and background colors as per your need, your stature is done,

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }




    #tittel-text {
        background-color: #d7a8a8;
    }

    #closse-text {
        color: #f2f2f2;
    }




    .text-pruduct {
        background-color: red;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .float_text {
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 40%;
    }


    .bild-text {
        background-color: #a6a6a6;
        display: flex;
        width: 60%;
    }
    .bild-text img {
        max-width: 200px;
    }

    .ajax-product-block {
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 10px 30px;
    }
    .ajax-product-block a {
        padding: 5px 15px;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="text-pruduct">
            
            <div class="bild-text">
                <img class="image-window" alt="" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/0DTr8HOTc3Q5uES2X1dk55jLRU58c0Rj8E_QTh2SyLDuTpIJWQl4_0HezDH2dOm4Yn3DZXjfVSMzasLNKtEmjw5lh_lumSwtd8AxDT2v2hhgP_vsBUGEVKTpt3vlx8fwt1P8oc08Z8UuoY80Bkz9GxTpY4tucV93T44VNa8qYF6bXlnaoCHcSbOy-NsCDfihRrc" />
                <div>
                    <p>Rucksack aus Hanf Gelbe</p>
                    <p>Stückzahl: <b>1</b></p>
                    <p>Bruttopreis: <b>40 &euro; </b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="float_text">
                <p>Anzahl der Artikel im Waremkorb: 1 </p>
                <p>Wert des Warenkorbs: </p>
            </div>
            <div class="ajax-product-block">
                <a class="button_weiter_einkaufen" href="lalo.php">weiter kaufen</a>
                <a class="button_zum_warenkorbs" href="lalo.php">zum warenkorb</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is what i to want!, I wisch you a nice day!